# Xcode Platform/Devices Simulator status

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode15

I am new to iOS development and downloaded all iOS and watchOS version simulators that are available and listed in Xcode. After successfully downloaded, some proceeds to install thus the status becomes "Installed" while other remains "x GB on Disk".

After restarting the laptop a couple of times, I am now randomly getting pop up like this.

[image]

Then all "Installed" status becomes "x GB on disk".

[image]

What is happening here and what is the difference between "Installed" and "x GB on disk" status?

I also noticed that there is a mounting disk that is not in the Runtime folder yet, do I need to manually mount it or move it before using those particular version? It seems that there are more need to do here after downloading it.

[image]